# How to change innodb_autoinc_lock_mode to be set to 0 from 1?

Tags: innodb

How to change the global variable `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` value 1 to 0 in MySQL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open your `my.cnf` and add the following line and make sure there is no space before or after the '=':

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
```

or start mysql with the command line parameter:

```
--innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
```

Comment: It's showing the error `Variable 'innodb_autoinc_lock_mode' is a read only variable`

Comment: cnf file loc on window: %PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini, %PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

If you’re searching for the my.cfg in Linux just as me, find it at '/etc/mysql'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).